# I can get the distance of shortest path here but how do i get the whole path

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

This is my approach. I have successfully got the shortest distance in this graph. But cant get the shortest path here.

```
import heapq as hq
graph = {
    1:{2:1, 4:2},
    2:{3:4, 5:5},
    3:{5:1},
    4:{3:2},
    5:{}
}


def dijkstra(G, src, dest):
    dist = {} # initializing our distances dict

    for v in G:
        dist[v] = float('inf')
        
    dist[src] = 0
    Q = [(0,src)]
    path = dict((key,[src]) for key in G) # i want all the paths here
    while len(Q) > 0:
        u, curr = hq.heappop(Q)

        if u > dist[curr]:
            continue
        for v, w in G[curr].items():
            d = u + w

            if d < dist[v]:
                dist[v] = d
                hq.heappush(Q, (d, v))
    return dist, path

start_point = 1
end_point = 5

print(dijkstra(graph, start_point, end_point))
```

I have used several methods except this but they didn't work.